# Most optimal way to log in bank websites and check transactions through scripting?

Tags: python, windows, web

I'm trying to automate my business by logging in bank websites and checking my transactions before releasing the goods to my clients. I'm trying to use python to do this. So far it works for facebook, I'm now trying on the bank website. But i was thinking, this method doesn't work if there's a change in the webpage. Is there any other optimal way to do this? There is no API provided btw. Thank you for your suggestions. Here's the code

```
from splinter import Browser

#userid
user_email = 'username'

# takes the password for the user account needed
user_pass = 'password'

# loads the firefox broswer
browser= Browser('firefox')

#selects bank as the website to load in the browser (have to load twice  because the bank directs it to the main site for the first time)
browser.visit('https://www.cimbclicks.com.my/wps/portal/!ut/p/c0/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9QJ_89Mw8_YJ0RUUAk9OZqw!!/')
browser.visit('https://www.cimbclicks.com.my/wps/portal/!ut/p/c0/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9QJ_89Mw8_YJ0RUUAk9OZqw!!/')

# fills the userid
browser.fill('userid', user_email)
#still working on the password part (unfinished)
browser.fill('pass', user_pass)

#selects the login button(so far doesn't work. I'm still working on how to click this image, can't find id. works for facebook though)

 button = browser.find_by_id('u_0_n')
 button.click()
```

Comment: Usually banks have interfaces for online banking software like HBCI. You should ask them.

Comment: Banks should have API for such online transactions and likely they do. btw, its better to use payment gateways instead. They are safe, secure and has API

Comment: the API is too expensive to use. I have to rule that option out

Answer (score 6):

You have found the major problem with web scraping. If the frontend changes, your code will fail.

There are generally two ways to overcome this:

1. Check if your bank websites have any APIs which you can use. These rarely change and if they do, most major corporations (like banks) version their APIs and still let you use a legacy version. So your code will never have to change.
2. Build checks into your code for UI changes. For example, if you are always expecting to find an HTML element with id `u_0_n` and suddenly all scrapes are not finding this HTML element, your code should alert you somehow through email, IM, syslog, *something*.

Web scraping is usually the quick, dirty solution. Try to exhaust all other possibilities first before you couple something as critical as billing with a technology as volatile as web scraping.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The bank's API is really costly and it takes away 60% of my profit. So, i ruled out that option. Is there a better alternative apart from my approach (splinter)?

Comment: Does your banking website have the option to email you transaction reports? You can use Python to consume these reports and thus eliminate the web scraping completely.

Comment: yes they do. I thought of this too but there are alot of phishing emails hence i dismiss off this idea. Would be safer to log in and check directly (bot)